# If I trade items through backpack.tf, will I be able to sell them on the community market?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've stopped playing TF2 after the Tough Break update, and I want to sell all my items on the community market. Some of my items are not marketable, but they are tradable. If I were to trade items from my inventory on backpack.tf for supply crate keys, would I be able to sell those keys on the market for money?

Comment: I think items become marketable 30 days after trading, if the item is able to be marketed in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, trading your non-marketable items for keys is a perfectly viable and valid way to get profit from your backpack items. It is highly recommended to have the mobile authenticator enabled, as a lot of traders do not want to wait the 1-3 day escrow period.